# Client/server application RPC connection gets disconnected very frequently

Tags: windows, rpc, client-server

I have a client/server application that uses RPC for the client to communicate with the server.

Fairly regularly, I get an event in the Application log that the RPC connection was disconnected:

```
 Client callback failed ((0x80010108) )
```

I have the Windows Firewall disabled on both machines.  I've even run the client on a second computer with a clean Windows XP install without any group policies.

This has been going on for a long time and no one has been able to figure out why it's happening.  The same client/server app works fine at other client locations.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

That will require some troubleshooting.

I would start by taking a [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Netmon](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f) trace of the network traffic and correlate the capture with when the error occurs to see if anything interesting crops up.  You could also take a look at the following article from TechNet Magazine: [Troubleshooting RPC Errors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.07.howitworks.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would do some basic elimination. Try each of the below steps, independently, until the error goes away.

1. Replace the ethernet cable on the client machine.
2. Replace the ethernet cable on the server machine.
3. Replace the NIC on the client machine.
4. Replace the NIC on the server machine.
5. Get a new switch and connect just those two computers together with it.
6. Try the client software on another machine.
7. Try the server software on another machine (if feasible).

Wireshark could probably give you a lot of info, but if you don't know how to analyze the data it may be overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from [this](http://www.eescodist.com/Customers/RSViewDCOMCustomerLetter.pdf) document:

> **DCOM 108 failure**
>
> Rockwell Automation and Microsoft has worked closely with some of our
>   mutual customers to identify and correct the DCOM 108 error, resulting
>   in a Microsoft update for the Microsoft Operating Systems affected.
>
> The Update for all Windows Operating Systems affected is available directly
>   through Microsfot support via http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924432.
>
> The updated code will be incorporated into Windows Server 2003 SP2.

The letter seems to fit what is happening to you.